# How to identify max value of one variable based on bins of a separate variable

Tags: r, mode, bin

I've seen a few binning questions, but haven't seen a solution to this case. Within a group_by condition, I'm trying to identify the mode, but the challenge is that the mode should consider the quantity of each observation (row), as defined by another column.

Within my data, each row represents an observation at a given time, and one column has `speed` while another has `quantity` values. If I run statistics on the `speed` it's ignoring the actual `quantity` during each observation. The `speed` is a continuous variable, so I know I want to bin (say 0-80 at increments of 5), and then sum the `quantity` of each bin, and finally report the `speed` bin with the highest quantity (a value that will be used in a separate calculation).

The bin label would preferably be the mid point (45-50 would be listed as 47.5). This would be run through a group of observations.

I've seen `count(cut_width())` but that's just observation counts, and not sure how to find max quantity. Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear from the examplee where the code begins and ends.  I believe the 2nd and 3rd line are input?

Comment: Also, `data.frame(speed = 0:80, value = runif(10))` do you expect it to work

Comment: And you have some package confusion... `group_by` is in `dplyr`, but `ddply` is in `plyr`. Loading `plyr` after `dplyr` will mask `dplyr` functions and cause problems. I'd strongly recommend **only** using `dplyr`.

Comment: And your code uses the column name `value`, while your text refers to `quantity`. If these are intended to be the same, please edit for consistency.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, the code was shown to give a hint of what i've tried but wasn't finished. I've removed it to avoid confusion. Agree that i'd prefer to only use `dplyr`

Comment: Well, the code was nice because it had sample data. Can you at least keep that? It's good to show what you tried, but the order of your lines was nonsense - you piped `group_by() %>%` into a stand-alone line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of my colleagues provided some good direction on this, and I found more content online.  One of the best ways is to look for a kde or density function that allows weights to influence the distribution.  In my case, I assigned a weight from the number of vehicles observed (Quantity) with each speed observation.

That direction led me here: https://rmflight.github.io/post/finding-modes-using-kernel-density-estimates/

Which has a great way to find the mode from a density function, so I only modified the density condition to add weight, and then set a bin width.

```
density_estimate <- density(data.calc$Speed, weights=data.calc$Quantity, bw=1)
```

and then the rest of the code from the github site

```
mode_value <- density_estimate$x[which.max(density_estimate$y)]
mode_value
```

My data is evaluated in groups, so I placed this to a loop (which I know people don't love) and was able to evaluate the mode by different time intervals.  Maybe this is all obvious, but I'm still learning and happy to find this method works.